# Clicking on a comment in your feed which has been moved to chat

Tags: bug, android-app

... fails to load question at all. (Error msg box.)

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-N950U1

  - OS Version: 8.0.0 (N950U1UES4CRE1)